# Windows 7 search is not working/acting weird

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, malware

I am fixing my cousins computer because it seems to be messed up. It just feels "weird". The first thing I tried was to search msconfig to see startup items. It's not working, and neither is any other seach. Any search I make comes up with some cobination of `Programs` and `Control Panel`. Is this a common problem with any simple fix? I did run `src /scannow` and it found some problem that it said it fixed. I still have the same problem though.

Also, I have IE and FF, but FireFox won't connect to any websites while IE will. Just one example of a "weird thing" going on

Comment: This sounds more like a virus to me. Have you ran a virus scan yet?

Comment: I am about to run MalwareBytes... should I go for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding some registry file that fixed it.

Here's the link.
http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-fix-windows-7-search-problems/

Steps from the link:
How to fix it manually:

1. Type regedit in Start menu search box and hit enter to launch Windows Registry Editor. Or, type regedit in Run dialog box (use Windows + R to launch Run) and hit enter to open the same.
2. Navigate to the following registry key:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}
3. Right-click on this sub key, and then select Delete.
4. Reboot your machine to fix the problem.
5. Done!

Comment: Would you mind sharing what the problem was and how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having lots of problems, if there's a product key from microsoft on the machine (If it's custom you might have to ask your cousin for the disk), just reinstall the OS. It should be much easier than dealing with all your problems.

Comment: That's what I figured, and that's what I do for most people installation, because they just have docs and pictures, but he has a ton of programs installed, so I was hoping there would be another route to take.

Comment: Oh so you are fixing this computer. I was under the impression that it was a gift. You might want to reword your question...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I reworded it now.